# How to solve this integral trigonometric integral or prove that is does not have a closed form solution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How would I solve this.
$$I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sqrt{\sec^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}\ dx$$
The approximate value of the integral:
$$I = 0.937723050585$$

I am trying to solve this integral to find the arc lenght of a parametric equation but do not see any trig substitution or other method to proceed.

I tried to use wolfram alpha but could not find a closed form solution. Is there a way to show the integral does not have a closed form?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why do you think it has a nice analytical solution?

Comment: @Andrei not sure, just wanted to check or find a proof of why it would not have an analytical solution.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm. And for fun, https://xkcd.com/2117/

Comment: Perhaps you could include the curve whose arc length you're trying to find? Best guess would be the curve (with Cartesian eq.) $y=\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}$ along $x\in[1,\sqrt2]$. Have you made any attempts to evaluate the integral since posting and editing? Looked over Mariusz's/Mathematica's solution?

Answer (score 0):

With help of [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/?source=nav) and [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org):

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \sqrt{\sec ^2(x)+\sin ^2(x)} \, dx=\\\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} -\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2-t^4}}{-1+t^2} \,
   dt=\\\frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) E\left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)|\frac{1}{2}
   \left(-3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)-\left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) F\left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)|\frac{1}{2}
   \left(-3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)+2 \Pi \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right);\csc
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)|\frac{1}{2} \left(-3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2 \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right)}}$$

Mathematica code:

`(1/Sqrt[2 (-1 + Sqrt[ 5])])((-1 + Sqrt[5]) EllipticE[ArcCsc[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5]]],  1/2 (-3 - Sqrt[5])] - (-1 + Sqrt[5]) EllipticF[ ArcCsc[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5]]], 1/2 (-3 - Sqrt[5])] +  2 EllipticPi[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), ArcCsc[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5]]],  1/2 (-3 - Sqrt[5])])`